# Does sequential 'new' operators make contiguous allocated memory?

Tags: c++

I heard std::vector is good because it guarantee contiguous allocated memory (cache-friendly). Then how about sequential 'new' operator like this?

```
{
    new Test1();
    new Test2();
    new Test3();
}
```

Does not it make contiguous allocated memory on heap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequential `new` expressions do not necessarily allocate sequential blocks of memory.

But C++14 has special support for such a sequence of `new` expressions, where under certain conditions they can be replaced with a single `new` expression (that necessarily allocates a sufficiently large chunk of contiguous memory), and where the corresponding `delete` expressions are replaced with a single `delete` expression.

*C++14 (N3936 draft) §5.3.4/10:*

> **”** An implementation is allowed to omit a call to a replaceable global allocation function (18.6.1.1, 18.6.1.2). When it does so, the storage is instead provided by the implementation or provided by extending the allocation of another `new`-expression. The implementation may extend the allocation of a `new`-expression `e1` to provide storage for a `new`-expression `e2` if the following would be true were the allocation not extended:
>   — the evaluation of `e1` is sequenced before the evaluation of `e2`, and
>   — `e2` is evaluated whenever `e1` obtains storage, and
>   — both `e1` and `e2` invoke the same replaceable global allocation function, and
>   — if the allocation function invoked by `e1` and `e2` is throwing, any exceptions thrown in the evaluation of either `e1` or `e2` would be first caught in the same handler, and
>   — the pointer values produced by `e1` and `e2` are operands to evaluated `delete`-expressions, and
>   — the evaluation of `e2` is sequenced before the evaluation of the `delete`-expression whose operand is the pointer value produced by `e1`.

Answer (score 0):

Memory management is really up to the operating system - at runtime, this is equivalent to calling the C `malloc` function several times in a row, i.e. contiguous allocation is not guaranteed (though likely). To guarantee that the objects are stored in a continuous memory block, they should be kept in an array.

I'm not sure what application you're going for, but in most cases the speed-up from the cache-friendliness is far outweighed by the overhead of passing around objects. cache-friendliness only speeds up programs that are operating on large databases (e.g. mergesort of a long array) because the CPU doesn't need to shuffle the array into and out of cache rapidly - however, for small numbers of objects, you don't have to worry about the cache because its effect will be so tiny. If you're declaring each vector individually, and not as a block in an array, I'm guessing there aren't that many of them, so putting them into an array is not needed and will not speed up your program.

Answer (score 0):

On most implementation the allocator would hold previously free'd memory, you would not expect to always get contiguous memory.

Think about this case: `Test1` is a large object, `Test2` is small one, `Test3` is a mid size.

When you allocate for `Test1`, the current memory pool don't have large enough reusable memory, so it request to extend the heap and allocate from there.
Then you do for the small `Test2`, it's just a tiny object that there is reusable memory from previously free'd one, so you get `Test2` from that pool.

For `Test3` its similar to `Test2`, but for performance the allocator would hold multiple pool for different size-range, so `Test3` may not go after `Test2`.

NOTE: All these are not mandatory from the specification, it's up to the implementation and what suggested here is just one of the usual implementation (further reading: Buddy memory allocation).